# CronJobs and print output perl

Tags: perl, cron

I wrote a script perl:

```
my $filename = '/root/report.txt';
open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print 'Hello world';
print $fh 'Hello world';
close $fh;
```

When I run this script with `perl script.pl`, it creates a log file $filename and Hello world is saved in the log file.

But if I use a cron job

```
* * * * * perl script.pl
```

it doesn't work and doesn't save in `report.txt`.

How do I solve this problem?

I tested it, when I used this script with PP:Parcker the log doesn't get saved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save output a cron in a file in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520769/how-to-save-output-a-cron-in-a-file-in-linux)

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34520769e/176646) multiple times. If the answers to your original question aren't satisfactory, leave a comment or edit the question instead of asking a new one. Also, you haven't provided enough detail in either question; did you check the cron log to make sure your cronjob actually ran? The log will also report any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when I first started using cron. The problem is, cron runs in a brand new shell, thus all your variables are gone, including the path.

Does your cron job include the FULL exact path to `perl` and `script.pl`? Because your example does not have the path to script.pl. Because the PATH variable is not saved when a cron job is run. The cron job may not have run but produced an error sent to your email account on that machine. Check your email too. And in the cron file put `MAIL=username`, so the email gets to your account on the machine the cron job is run. If your machine supports sending email outside that machine the job is run on, set `MAIL=me@othermachine.com`.

To set the path, in the cron file set `PATH=/whatever:/somewhere/else`.

Also, are you editing your personal crontab file with `crontab -e`? That's normally recommended. Do not touch the system crontabs.

Another variable you can set is `SHELL=/bin/bash` to use bash for all cron jobs.

Also, what Jens said about using the full path for perl and your script.
You have no path when the cron job runs unless you set it in the crontab file as in my suggestion above.

```
# Suggested crontab file edited with crontab -e.
# This is a crontab comment.
MAIL=me
PATH=/usr/bin:/root
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * /usr/bin/perl/perl /export/home/me/script.pl
```

Key points:

1. Cron runs in it's own shell which you can set in using the SHELL=
   variable. You will also have no variables unless you set them.
2. Use full path to perl and the script every time.
3. Cron only sends you an email if screen output is produced, either
   via the program or an error message. It can be tricky to track down
   a blank cron email where the only output was a carriage return.
4. Edit local crontab files only, using `crontab -e` on Ubuntu. Might
   be different on other systems.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read your email. Cron has sent you one.

Next, understand that cron started jobs have possibly your home directory as the current working directory. Chances are, `script.pl` is somewhere else.
Try using

```
* * * * * * /path/to/perl /path/to/script.pl
```

Please check twice (by reading `man 5 crontab`) if the crontab accepts six asterisks. My implementation on FreeBSD accepts only 5.

Comment: i can't using Perl before path/to/script because i using Par:Parcker encryption my script.

Comment: @YasinSanjari One of us is confused. If `perl script.pl` works, then `/path/to/perl /path/to/script.pl` works as well. Just use the full path names.